# Entity framework strings using greater than operator

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-4.1

How do I make this query work like it does in sql?  In sql I can use `<` and `>` operators on strings.

I've been googling this for about 20 minutes and have found no solution yet.

I cannot convert r.ExemptionCode to an integer as it may have values like '91A,9AA,ZZZ,Z01'

```
from r in results
where (r.ExemptionCode > "900"  || r.ExemptionCode == "701" || r.ExemptionCode == "702" || r.ExemptionCode == "721" || r.ExemptionCode == "724")
select r
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try using [`.CompareTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto):

```
from r in results
where (r.ExemptionCode.CompareTo("900") > 0  || r.ExemptionCode == "701" || r.ExemptionCode == "702" ||     r.ExemptionCode == "721" || r.ExemptionCode == "724")
select r
```

Comment: Copy and pasted straight from my brain.  Good Job.  I figured this out after extensive use of the immediate window! XD

Comment: altho it didn't solve my issue based on the answer, you pointed me in the correct direction, which was in my case `String.Compare(a.version, b.version, System.StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0` - thanks +1

Comment: Works with EF Core 3.1 also. If someone wonders. `SomeTables.Where(l => l.SomeField.CompareTo("A 102") >= 0 && l.SomeField.CompareTo("A 104") <= 0)` generated `SELECT [s].[someField]
FROM [SomeTable] AS [s]
WHERE (CASE
    WHEN [s].[someField] = N'A 102' THEN 0
    WHEN [s].[someField] > N'A 102' THEN 1
    WHEN [s].[someField] < N'A 102' THEN -1
END >= 0) AND (CASE
    WHEN [s].[someField] = N'A 104' THEN 0
    WHEN [s].[someField] > N'A 104' THEN 1
    WHEN [s].[someField] < N'A 104' THEN -1
END <= 0)` in my case.

Comment: While this works, it appears less than optimal in the SQL sense. Generating a WHERE CASE statement pulls every possible record from the DB, to be filtered in the application tier.

Any suggestions on a LINQ expression that generates something like `WHERE LastName BETWEEN 'Pat' AND 'Pet'`

Comment: A bit more research on my side, and this answer appears to be an excellent approach to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59095579/1088293

Comment: In EF Core 7 (and possibly before), `string.Compare(myCol, myStr) >= 0` actually gets translated to `myCol >= @myStr` which is perfect.